# Delete button in append element is not working

Tags: jquery, append, getvalue

My DELETE button doesn't work

Here is the code :

```
    $('.postGlobalWrap').on('click', '.delete', function(){
          removeNote();
    });
```

FULL PEN :
https://codepen.io/Podgro/pen/xxxxPNR

I need your help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try using

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
```

instead of

```
var parent = $(this).closest('li');
```

and

```
$('.postGlobalWrap').on('click', '.delete', function(){
     removeNote($(this));
 });

function removeNote(del_btn) {
  console.log('test');
  var parent = del_btn.parent();
  console.log(parent);
  parent.fadeOut();
  parent.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thx... i don't know why i didn't do this :D

Comment: your welcome, sometimes we miss even the big details in which we may just see with our eyes :D